# Can't do a simple division

Tags: c#, function, xna, division

I'm working on Responsive Design for my game. I recalculate position for my object in function of the screen size. I'm doing the good calcul but my function give me the wrong result always returning 0. 
I need the return value to be an Int.

Here the code :

```
public int rdnW(int a)
{
    double b;

    b = (a / 800 * 100);
    return (int)(b * Widths / 100);
}
```

With breakpoints i have see that b is always = 0; In my case a = 258. Thanks

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hard to believe that a post that is possibly a duplicate of scores of questions has 6 answers without a single close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast `a` to double so the result of the calculation will not be rounded.

```
b = ((double)a / 800 * 100);
```

Comment: I think you meant "cast a to double", not "declare a as double"

Comment: Thanks, what a subtility ..

Answer (score 7):

You are performing integer division. Cast one of the values to `double` or `float` or specify one of the constants as a double: i.e. 100.0 instead of 100.

Example

```
b = (a / 800.0 * 100.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
b = ((double)a / 800 * 100);
```

That's because the expression is evaluated as `integer` because all the factors are integer. After the evaluation of the expression it is saved into a `double` variable.

You can also use something similar to:

```
b = (a / 800.0 * 100);
```

or

```
b = (a / 800 * 100.0); //in your case this will return zero because (a/800) will be evaluated as integer
```

It is necessary that at least one of the factors is a double to "tell" to the compiler that the expression have a `double` type

Comment: I think the last one would be evaluated as `(a / 800) * 100.0` which would not fix the (whole) problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because what you done is here *integer division*. If `a` and `b` are integer and `a < b` , `a / b` always give you `0` as a result regardless which type you assign it or cast it.

In your cause, `a` is probably less than `800` so that's why it gives `0` as a result.

.NET has 3 type of division. From [`7.7.2 Division operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

- Integer division
- Floating-point division
- Decimal division

From *Integer division* part;

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands.

From [`/ Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. To determine the remainder of 7 /
>   3, use the remainder operator (%). **To obtain a quotient as a rational
>   number or fraction, give the dividend or divisor type float or type
>   double.**

As a solution, you can cast double your `a` or `800` like;

```
b = ((double)a / 800 * 100);
```

or

```
b = (a / 800d * 100);
```